# How to modify an image by inserting another image?

Tags: vb.net

I have an image (800x800p) loaded in a PictureBox. It's slightly interactive, clicking somewhere on it will show tooltips or popup windows.

Occasionally, clicking would result in adding of 100x100 px image on the location where it was clicked. That modification needs to be saved onto the main image.

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: Draw the new image over your original image. There are a few ways and you can find them with simple google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the new image over your original image.
For example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseClick
        Dim NewIMG As New Bitmap(100, 100)
        Graphics.FromImage(NewIMG).Clear(Color.Black) 'just to make my image black since I don't have any image

        'You drawing new image here
        Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image).DrawImage(NewIMG, New Point(e.X - 50, e.Y - 50)) 'mouse position - half new image size so that new image center is placed at cursor location
        PictureBox1.Refresh() 'to make picbox redraw and display new image
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

Comment: It did work, I hadn't the faintest idea it was just that simple... Thank you so much.